# failing to import project to android studio downloaded from internet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I tried to import project which is downloaded from *http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game_libgdx/Download_Free_code_PestalotiopsisMicrospora.htm*.

It is showing following image. Please help me what to put in the path:

[image: Path image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing the root directory of the project where the AndroidManifest.xml exists.

From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) might help you out. It has explained the steps along with pictures how to do so

Import as a Project:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project.
     Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, click Import project (Eclipse,ADT, Gradle, etc).
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.
4. Select the destination folder and click Next.
5. Select the import options and click Finish.

[image]

Comment: please see the image attached in the question.What should i write in the space. in the image above

Comment: wherever your project is stored in the directory. e.g if my project is stored in D:/some-folder i would provide its path.

Comment: please see the image above when i entered path and clicked next it is asking Enter the value for workspace path libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar

Comment: please help me sachin

Comment: please would you send me the screenshot of it. I already did it  and I am getting no error !

Comment: please give your mail id .I will send the screenshot

Comment: You should send the screenshot here.

Comment: how to add screen shot in comment

Comment: I am new to SO please help me.

Comment: please help me sachin how to add screenshot

Comment: Try editing your answer and post your screenshot there.

Comment: for that i need 10 reputation

Comment: I tried but i need 10 reputation to post more than 2 images

Comment: I have answered the question with two images .please help me seeeing those images

Comment: mail me here sachinb0013@gmail.com

Comment: my guess is you need to download those jars manually, does the jar files exist in the project itself?